# Is it possible to beam someone against their will?

Tags: star-trek, teleportation

In *Star Trek* (any series) it would seem the transporter would make a great defensive weapon against your ship being boarded - simply start beaming the intruders into a holding cell (or if you're feeling particularly cruel, into space or just delete their patterns from the buffer altogether)

But my question is, is it possible to beam someone against their will?  If not, then this would explain why this is never done.

I know we have seen "surprise" transportations - Data in TNG: *The Most Toys*, Kirk and McCoy in *The Undiscovered Country*. But I can't think of any where someone has not wanted to be transported or has tried to physically resist it.

Comment: I can remember when someone tried to resist being transported, I remember it being immensely painful . . . let me google.

Comment: They beam prisoners all the time. So yes

Comment: Except that one time that the guy was an enhanced, and resisted.

Comment: "this would explain why this is never done" — so would lots of other things. How often do you see ships being boarded in Star Trek when they haven't already suffered enough damage to take down their shields, possibly take down their transporters, and give their crew enough other things to cope with aside from trying to lock on to hostile individuals within their own ship, who are probably moving around, and don't have handy Starfleet com-badges to focus on.

Comment: As a counter-argument, weren't they initially able to beam the Borg borders away and then they couldn't when they adjusted their personal shields?  Or am I misremembering?

Comment: I think the Borg adjusted their personal shields to match the frequency the humans' phasers were set to. But given that at least some versions of the Enterprise had difficulty beaming through enemy shields, it would not surprise me if the Borg were also able to resist being beamed away.

Comment: A better question would be is it possible to resist?

Comment: Part of the issue with using transporters as weapons are 1) shields being up 2) the amount of energy it requires to constantly run the transporter systems in that manner 3) transport inhibitor tech 4) one would have to assume the computer can understand and register the invading species as a targetable life form (what if the species is not registered in the database, so the sensors can’t detect them correctly?) and finally 5) we would have to assume both ships or all ships are in an area of space that doesn’t cause transporter chaos and malfunction, making them useless. Lots of variables.

Comment: I'm curious -- what is your idea of how to "physically resist" a transporter?  Once you are caught in the transporter effect, I do not believe you can physically do anything.  Maybe, psychically resist?

Comment: People aren't beamed against their will for the same reason that I don't walk up to random strangers and run my fingers through their hair even though there's nothing physically stopping me.

Comment: Can you explain in what way the subject's will might be relevant? Could the target's will resist my rifle bullet, or phaser beam? 

For one thing, no few episodes of each genre clearly feature people being beamed against their will… usually bad guys, but not always?

After you've found a way to rule out those episodes, what are you suggesting?

Comment: Yes, if you fail a "wisdom" saving throw.

Comment: One of the most powerful characters in the canon was beamed against his will ("The Survivors"), so the obvious answer is yes.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - if someone was trying to break into your house and you knew they had a weak spot on their scalp that makes them fall asleep, you might do it...

Comment: @Basya "what is your idea of how to "physically resist" a transporter?" - no idea!

Comment: @colmde -- OK, thanks.  I was just kind of surprised by the question because I couldn't imagine what it would mean to resist it.  Physically?  Telepathically?  How would a person's will keep the thing from breaking him up into his component parts and moving them somewhere else?  This was quite beyond me!

Comment: @colmde I guess that's my point. You don't do it because it's a violation of their freedom and bodily autonomy. But physically there's nothing stopping you.

Comment: Oh please — here is an example of someone transported against their will: https://youtu.be/k41ZPS6faRE

Answer (score 37):

### Yes, you can beam people against their will in Star Trek.

We've seen several examples of Starfleet officers being kidnapped via alien transporters.

For example, in *[Ménage à Troi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_%C3%A0_Troi_(episode))*, Riker, Deanna, and Lwaxana Troi were forcibly beamed off of the planet Betazed by Ferengi transporters.

And in *[The Mind's Eye](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mind%27s_Eye_(episode))*, La Forge was forcibly beamed off of a shuttlecraft by Romulan transporters.

Even if you discount examples such as those, on the basis that they involved *alien* transport tech, there are multiple examples of *Starfleet* transporters being used to beam people against their will.

For example, in *[Datalore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Datalore_(episode))*, [Lore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lore) was thrown (by Data) onto a transporter pad and beamed into space.

And in *[A Matter Of Honor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Matter_Of_Honor_(episode))*, [Captain Kargan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kargan) was forcibly beamed off of his ship and onto the bridge of the Enterprise-D.

We've also seen instances where characters in *Star Trek* knew an attempt might be made to beam them somewhere against their will, and used technological means to prevent it.

For example, in *[Power Play](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Power_Play_(episode))*, Troi, Data, and O'Brien were possessed by alien entities, and were holding people hostage in [Ten Forward](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ten_Forward). An attempt was made to get a transporter lock on the possessed officers, but O'Brien took the transporters offline in order to prevent that.

> **RIKER:** Transporter room three, can you get a pattern lock on Commander Data, Counselor Troi and Chief O'Brien in Ten Forward?
>
> **CREWMAN:** Attempting to lock on, sir.
>
> **O'BRIEN:** You were correct. They're attempting to engage their transporters. But I know how to shut them down.
>
> **DATA:** Do it.
>
> **CREWMAN:** Bridge, the entire transporter array has been taken off line and placed into diagnostic mode.
>
> <sub>[Star Trek: TNG "Power Play" script](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/215.htm)</sub>

And in *[Star Trek: Insurrection](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection)*, Data used a [transport inhibitor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transport_inhibitor) to prevent himself from being beamed off of a [scoutship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_mission_scoutship) after the shields had been briefly disabled.

The very existence of transport inhibitors is strong evidence that desire alone is not enough to prevent oneself from being transported (at least, not for non-augments).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Fumble fingers.

Comment: There are several TOS examples where non-crewmembers (aliens or Old Earth humans) were transported against their will. "A Piece of the Action" and "Tomorrow is Yesterday" are two.

Comment: @Ross Presser  - Yeah, I thought about mentioning some of those, but it occurred to me that most of those instances involved characters from pre-warp civilisations who didn't even know what a transporter was, meaning they had no idea what was occurring when they were beamed up to the ship. Whereas with Starfleet officers, or other people familiar with transporter tech, they would likely know if they were being forcibly transported, and would therefore be more apt to consciously resist the process.

Comment: The Romulan Commander in "The Enterprise Incident" tried to stop Spock from being transported -- and ended up being transported with him.  She was unable to prevent it either for him or for herself.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would go about 'consciously resisting' being transported, but if you recognise the symptoms that the process is starting (say, an all-over tingling sensation) would it be possible for you to run away from the point the transporter is focused on?

Comment: @LogicDictates There was a canonical instance of someone "consciously resisting" being transported, it was the decommissioned Special Operations solider from S03E11 of TNG, The Hunted (https://www.denofgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/star_trek_tng_1.jpg). It looked like it took a massive effort, resulted in an explosion and it seemed very unusual, but he was able to break out of the transporter lock.

Comment: Season 3 Episode 3 of TNG, "The Survivors" includes beaming the titular survivors to the bridge against their will. They are moving around at the time too. That shows federation beaming technology used in that manner, which does not seem to be in your list otherwise.

Comment: @Basya - Yeah, that's another good example.

Comment: @GordonD - I doubt it. When Roga Danar resisted transport -- as mentioned in [Withad's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/243653/122024) below -- it seemed like he had to physically strain to break free of the annular confinement beam, as if it were a force field holding him in place. Conversely, in the _Enterprise_ episode, _The Augments_, Captain Archer was successfully transported as he was hurtling out of an airlock and into space. These examples appear to contradict each other, but neither one suggests you could just run away once transport has begun.

Comment: @Simon Hova - Yup. Withad covered that in [his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/243653/122024) below.

Comment: @fectin - I wasn't attempting to compile a complete list; just enough examples to effectively make my point. I actually don't think the instance in _The Survivors_ is a very good example, as Kevin Uxbridge seemed to have powers comparable to that of a Q, and likely could have stopped himself from being transported if he'd wanted. My impression is that he was caught by surprise and didn't consciously resist.

Comment: @LogicDictates fair. I was looking for a federation example, not a complete list, but fair.

Comment: @fectin - My answer lists six examples in total. One Ferengi, one Romulan, two successful Starfleet attempts, and two failed Starfleet attempts (thwarted by technological countermeasures). So if you wanted a Federation example, my answer already provided at least two.

Answer (score 21):

Under normal circumstances, **yes**, it is possible to beam someone against their will.

In *Star Trek: Insurrection*, [transport inhibitors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transport_inhibitor) are used to prevent the Son'a transporting the Ba'ku en masse. Later, the Son'a use darts with [isolinear tags](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Isolinear_tag) to overcome the jamming. If it was possible for the Ba'ku to simply resist the transporter beam, this would all have been unnecessary.

Also, as a sort of exception that proves the rule, there's the supersoldier Roga Danar in the *TNG* episode ["The Hunted"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hunted_(episode)). He resists a transporter beam thanks to his genetic/chemical enhancements and doing so causes a small explosion. You can see it about 20 seconds into [the episode trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=21&v=lQ52ebFqzdI).

Danar was known to be dangerous and a flight risk but everyone still expected the transporter to work on him, suggesting that overcoming a transporter is something they hadn't seen before and that ordinary people can't do.

Comment: Khan also resists in the reboot thingie

Comment: @Valorum I love the thought that they changed so much in the reboot but absolutely had to keep the fact that there's a special anti-transporter gene supersoldiers can get.

Answer (score 3):

> this would explain why this is never done

So would lots of other things. How often do we see ships being boarded in Star Trek when they haven't already suffered enough damage to take down their shields, and possibly take down their transporters too?

In situation like that, the crew has enough things to cope with other than trying to lock on to hostile individuals within their own ship, who are probably moving around, and don't have handy Starfleet com-badges to focus on.

Comment: Not really an answer but I would have thought there were a lot of instances where ships would have been boarded by unwelcome guests, the transporters were still working and where a crew member could have been spared to man it, especially considering they could make it a priority, especially if the boarding party was small enough, or to protect key areas of the ship (like the bridge or engine room)

Comment: "I would have thought there were a lot of instances where ships would have been boarded by unwelcome guests, the transporters were still working and where a crew member could have been spared to man it" — maybe there were, and we just didn't see them. We certainly don't see the Enterprise being boarded much.

Comment: This may be much like planetary invasions; if you're just trying to *defeat* them, it's much more efficient to stick to ship-to-ship/planet combat; if you have to send people over/down, you're doing it wrong. (There are exceptions, though, e.g. if your objective isn't the whole ship/planet, but information, or a particular artifact, or... Basically, boarding actions are for surgical strikes, not all out combat. Even for capturing ships, you usually don't board until *after* the ship surrenders.)